# Unable to trigger .tab in bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to trigger programmatically .tab in my code to open a tabs on swipe, the issue is that .tab('show') doesn't do nothing and doesn't cast any error..

here is my code:

```
<nav class="nav-scroller mt-2 mb-3" role="tablist">
   <div
      class="nav nav-pills flex-column flex-sm-row"
      role="tablist"
      >
      <a
         class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link active"
         data-toggle="tab"
         href="#verdura"
         aria-controls="verdura"
         role="tab"
         >Verdura</a
         >
      <a
         class="flex-sm-fill text-sm-center nav-link"
         data-toggle="tab"
         href="#frutta"
         aria-controls="frutta"
         role="tab"
         >Frutta</a
         >
   </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="verdura" role="tabpanel">VERDURA</div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="frutta" role="tabpanel">FRUTTA</div>
</div>
```

And in JS after getting the active nav-link i do the following:

```
var curActive = $(nav).find(".active")
// here i the user swipe and i do this
          var newActive = curActive.next()
          $(newActive).addClass("active")
$(newActive).tab('show') // AND HERE I SHOULD TRIGGER THE TAB BUT IT'S NOT WORKING
```

Comment: did you try to console.log newActive?

Comment: @GertB yes and it's the right element where there is the href to the tav

Comment: I would try to remove the line where you set it to active.

Comment: @GertB. yeah that was it i don't even need removeClass('active') thank you

Comment: i'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added the active class, so the tabs code thinks the tab is already open:

```
var curActive = $(nav).find(".active")
// here i the user swipe and i do this
          var newActive = curActive.next()
$(newActive).tab('show')
```

the active state will be automatically set.